# Monorepo-The lockfile would have been modified by this install, which is explicitly forbidden

Tags: dockerfile, hadoop-yarn, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am trying monorepo and using yarn workspaces to handle the below scenario.

root/

- Package.json
- yarn.lock
- moduleA/

  - package.json
  - yarn.lock
- moduleB/

  - package.json
  - yarn.lock

In root package.json we have
"workspaces": {packages: [moduleA/, moduleB/]}

We are generating lock file using `yarn install` command.

We have dockerfiles for both modules ModuleA & ModuleB

We are just copying respective module in their dockerfile, and while exceuting this command `yarn install` we get this error **The lockfile would have been modified by this install, which is explicitly forbidden**

This is obivous because when we are generating lock file from local we have both modules present but in while docker build we have only one module present

What we have tried and didn't worked in ModuleA Dockerfile

```
yarn workspaces moduleA install
```

```
yarn install
```

We read that we can set environment variable `YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS` this can be used, but our expectation is that if we have workspaces for respective modules then this might be very common problem then there will be some best way to resolve this issue.

Any help will be appreciated to deal with this.

Comment: you can't use `yarn workspaces moduleA install`
either `yarn workspace moduleA install` (without s) for just one workspace or 
`yarn install` in the root package folder for all packages